# How to make distributor highly available in Always On Configuration

Tags: availability-groups, transactional-replication, high-availability

We have clients requested us to configure Always on with Replication. Microsoft does not support it. "The distributor should not be a host for any of the current (or intended) replicas of the availability group that the publishing database is (or will become) a member of. " We do not want distributor to be on the same server as Publisher.
Has anyone faced this change? Do you know the limitation for not having distributor as replica of the availability group. What other options do you recommend to have high availability for distributor in transactional replication in Always on Configuration.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put the distributor in a virtual machine, and use the hypervisor's high availability tools. This lets you survive host hardware failure. OS problems will still cause issues, though, so for an additional level of protection, you can run clusters inside virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting the Distributor in an AlwaysOn Availability Group of it's own on two different servers and make the secondary a synchronous replica? Besides, there's real benefit in a high volume OLTP environment to not having the Distributor on the same SQL Server.